# Need a little clarifying on dividing orders of elements of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

I am reading a little proof here and can't seem to see what theorem they use:

> Claim: Let G be a group with $a \in G$ and $\text{ord}(a)$ finite. If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $\text{ord}(aH) \mid \text{ord}(a).$
>
> Proof: Let $m = \text{ord}(a)$. Then $\text{ord}(aH)^m = a^mH = eH = H$. Thus $\text{ord}(aH) \mid m.$

I know that $\text{ord}(a) \mid m$ if $a^m = e.$ What they seem to be saying is that $\text{ord}(aH) \mid m$ if $(aH)^m = H.$ Are these the same theorem? Any connection between $e$ and $H$?

Comment: Yes, they use the same theorem. Think about what the identity is in the quotient group, and you will see they are saying the same thing.

The coset $H$, or $eH$, is the identity in the quotient group. Therefore, if a power of a coset gives you $H$, then it is saying that power of the coset is the identity. This is exactly what you are doing in the group $G$ when you see $a^m = e$.

So the connection is $e$ is the identity in $G$, while $H=eH$ is the identity in the quotient group $G/H$.

Comment: @User0112358, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion is about the role of $H$ in the quotient group.

$H$ is the identity in the quotient group. Think of $eH$. What is $eH$? Well, $e$ times some element is just the same element, so $eH=H$. Thus, for any $a \in G$, we have the following:

$$H(aH)=(eH)(aH)=(ea)H=aH$$
$$(aH)H=(aH)(eH)=(ae)H=aH$$

Therefore, $H$ is the identity element in the quotient group because any element times it is just the same element.

Comment: Cheers! Thanks.